# Query DynamoDB with different PK values

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, dynamodb-queries

I am trying to use [`query`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb/client/query.html) with `KeyConditionExpression` in Boto3 to query a DynamoDB table.

I am trying to return all the records using the following sudo expression

```
(PK=X AND SK=Y) OR (PK=A AND SK=B)
```

OR

```
KeyConditionExpression=((Key("PK").eq(f"USERID#{user_id}") & Key("SK").eq(f"PROJECTID#{project_id}")) | (Key("PK").eq(f"USERID#{user_id}PROJECTID#{project_id}") & Key("SK").begins_with("LAYERID#")))
```

PK is the primary key and SK is the Sort Key.
Does this need to be 2 separate queries and the results join or can it be done in one?

Comment: Did the supplied answer help? Is this resolved?

Answer (score 1):

Given that you know the complete key for each item, you don't need to use query.

You can issue two [get_item](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb/client/get_item.html) calls or a single [batch_get_item](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb/client/batch_get_item.html) call.